# How to delete trash items using terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, trash

I have some important and some unimportant items in trash.

I need to delete the unimportant files from trash, but when I empty the trash, my important files are also deleted.

How to delete trash items using terminal in MacOS?

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sudo rm --f

Then Drag and drop the file(s) you wish to delete onto the open Terminal window

Read more: [How to Delete Files Using the Terminal in Mac OS X | eHow.com](http://www.ehow.com/how_4530950_delete-terminal-mac-os-x.html#ixzz13THZKM5MBlockquote)